# "The Errors of TeX" with hyperlinks

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex

I was reading the appendix to "The Errors of TeX" by Knuth ([`errorlog.tex`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/systems/knuth/dist/errata/errorlog.tex), written with plain TeX) and I noticed that there is a PDF file [`errorlog.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/errata/errorlog.pdf) with nice hyperlinks and I was wondering how that is possible.

It looks like magic to me, since the plain TeX file apparently has nothing related to hyperlinks. I've noticed that the PDF file was generated with `pdftex`, so I was wondering if there is some `pdftex`-specific technique allowing such hyperlinks.

Does anybody know what kind of modifications are necessary (if any) in order to compile Knuth's file with `pdftex` and get those hyperlinks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `errorlog.pdf` is actually generated by project [`latex-tds`](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/latex-tds.html). The aim of the project is the generation of hyper features like links and bookmarks to the documentation of LaTeX(2e)
and some more or less close bundles (tools, amsmath, ...).

`errorlog.tex` loads `logmac.tex` that defines the macros used in `errorlog.tex`. Project `latex-tds` has some patches in `logmac.tex.diff` that adds the links for pdfTeX.
The generation of `errorlog.pdf` is done by running pdfTeX on the driver file `errorlog.drv` of project `latex-tds`. It contains some media size setting stuff and defines the fields title and author for the PDF information dictionary. Then it loads `errorlog.tex` that includes the modified `logmac.tex` with hyper link support.

Comment: I don't see any hyperlink stuff in `logmac.tex` on CTAN (it's dated 1991): could we have a clue as to where the appropriate code is?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I compiled the tex file myself with pdftex and got no hyperlinks. The logmac.tex file I have (it's in the directory where the errorlog.tex is) is from 1991 as Joseph pointed out.

Comment: @JosephWright I forgot, the modifications to add link support is also be done by `latex-tds`. I have rewritten the answer.